# XSLT - Generate easier xml structure to avoid grouping

Tags: xslt, grouping

How can I convert this document:

```
<Root>
  <!-- yes, I know I don't need a 'Root' element! Legacy code... -->
  <Plans>
    <Plan AreaID="1" UnitID="83">
      <Part ID="9122" Name="foo" />
      <Part ID="9126" Name="bar" />
    </Plan>
    <Plan AreaID="1" UnitID="86">
      <Part ID="8650" Name="baz" />
    </Plan>
    <Plan AreaID="2" UnitID="26">
      <Part ID="215" Name="quux" />
    </Plan>
    <Plan AreaID="1" UnitID="95">
      <Part ID="7350" Name="meh" />
    </Plan>
  </Plans>
</Root>
```

to:

```
<areas>
    <area id="1">
        <unit id="83">
            <part id="9122">foo</part>
            <part id="9126">bar</part>
        </unit>     
        <unit id="86">
            <part id="8650">baz</part>          
        </unit>     
        <unit id="95">
            <part id="7350">meh</part>          
        </unit>
    </area> 
    <area id="2">
        <unit id="26">
            <part id="215">quux</part>          
        </unit>             
    </area>
</areas>
```

Do I need to group area elements?

Comment: looks like you are missing part of your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="Plan" use="@AreaID"/>

  <xsl:template match="Plans">
    <areas>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Plan[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', @AreaID)[1])]" mode="group"/>
    </areas>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Plan" mode="group">
    <area id="{@AreaID}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', @AreaID)"/>
    </area>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Plan">
    <unit id="{@UnitID}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </unit>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Part">
    <part id="{@ID}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </part>
  </xsl:template>      

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. Apparently using grouping is required for the purpose?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, do you want to avoid any grouping constructs in the XSLT code? I could think about other approaches but I don't think they are easier to write or more efficient when being executed.